# How to detect C++ function attributes at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Is there any way to detect if a function has a certain attribute attached to it?

I would like to specialise a template class, whose template argument is a type with a well-defined method, based on the attributes of that method.

For example, GCC has attributes like `__attribute__(noreturn)` and C++11 has attributes like `[[noreturn]]` .

I would like to propagate such attributes through my template:

```
template <typename T>
struct Proxy {
  void call() {
    T::call();
  }
};
```

with something like

```
template <typename T>
struct Proxy {
  [[noreturn if_has_attribute(noreturn, T::call)]] 
  void call() {
    T::call();
  }
};
```

or

```
template <typename T>
struct Proxy {
  [[copy_attrbiutes_from(T::call)]] 
  void call() {
    T::call();
  }
};
```

or via some template specialisation.

So, is there any (possibly `constexpr`) way to detect a function's attributes?
Either for GCC attributes, or for standard C++11 attributes?

Comment: The standard does not provide any such feature.  Attributes are not part of the type system; they are essentially just a unified markup syntax for common compiler extensions.  So if there is any way to do this at all (which I doubt), it is not going to be portable.

Comment: I understand.
Does anybody know of a way to do it with GCC and/or Clang ?

Comment: Is there some reasonable benefit? The compiler/optimiser should propagate [[noreturn]] if it is any good, omitting the exit path in the template, and in its calling function.

Comment: Not for this example - but I wanted to give a simple example for people to look at.